# Navigating a control (ListBox) time-lag

Tags: automation, delay, autohotkey, timedelay

While making AutoHotkey-script I encountered the following problem. I need navigate listbox (one position to lower direction). If the current selected line is a bottom line of visible listbox area, then navigation will take longer than if the selection is above the last line. There is an illustrating [video](http://youtu.be/XtpSic4PvVg) of this behavior. (***EDIT:*** As I understand it, there is an extra-time to redraw listbox)

The following script doesn't work for the selected bottom-line.

```
Send, {tab}   ; Set focus to ListBox
Send, {down}  ; Navigate Listbox
Send, {enter} ; Submit selection
```

So, I can insert `Sleep, 200` after second line. However, there maybe more elegant solution. If such a solution exists, describe it to me, please.

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet (there aren't any sentences ending with a ?).

Comment: @HonestAbe: I'm not a native English speaker. Was I explain my problem clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you're talking about.

There really isn't anything inelegant about adding one Sleep command if it makes things work well.
Sleep is very often needed when using the Send command for things to work smoothly, in various applications. This is because the Send command sometimes sends artificial keystrokes faster than the application is designed to handle. I have needed to write scripts like:

```
Send, {x down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {x up}
```

for it to work in several applications, to simulate the press duration.
There is of course `SetKeyDelay` but then you don't have as fine of control.

Another option is using `GuiControl` to select things.
Here is a rough example:

```
Gui, Add, DropDownList, vColorChoice, Black|White|Red|Green|Blue
Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice Choose1 AltSubmit h120, Red|Green|Blue|Black|White
Gui, Show, h156

loop 4
{
Gui, Submit, nohide
sleep, 1000
GuiControl, Choose, Choice, % Choice + 1
Send, {enter}{tab}
} Return
```

It's a demonstration, not a practical script.
To select something specific it would look like:

```
GuiControl, Choose, Choice, 3
```